# Images not rendering in react-native-render-html

Tags: html, json, image, react-native

I am trying to use react-native-render-html to display some text and images inline.

The HTML is part of a JSON object, so for example:

```
exercises: [
   {
      title: 'exercise 1',
      description: '<p>This is a test</p> <img src="../assets/images/my-image.png"> <p>Blah blah blah</p>',
   },
],
```

The location of the file containing the HTML: **./src/constants.js**
The location of the image I am trying to render: **./assets/images/my-image.png**
The location of the file trying to render the HTML: **./src/components/pages/page.js**

For some reason, the text shows but the image shows an empty square, which according to the docs, means the image link is broken. However, I created an HTML file to test and it renders perfectly in chrome. I've tried changing the image source path to its location from the file it's located in, the file it's called in etc. but nothing works. The file is in my assets folder which is in my root directory.

This is how I am trying to render the HTML:

```
<HTML
   html={this.props.exerciseSelected.description}
   imagesMaxWidth={WIDTH}
   baseFontStyle={styles.descriptionText}
/>
```

Looking at the issues on the repo, it appears a few people have had similar issues and used custom renderers, but the docs are quite poor and I'm not sure if that is even the solution. Also to note, if I try to require the file and use a basic react-native Image component, it shows on the page. But really, this is no help to me, I'm trying to statically render over 50 articles that have images and text in different places so I can't just pick out the images and render them this way because it will be difficult to determine where the image should be located on the page.

Please let me know if I am making a silly mistake, or if you know of a better package to use that should solve my issue.

Any help would be appreciated :-)

Comment: Same issue, i have some injected HTML in a webview and I can render & style most components, buttons, paragraphs etc - but I can't get <img/> to work - I am trying to get the file locally as follows:  <img src="../assets/images/mangopay-white.png" alt="Logo" width="400" height="125" >. I have tried a require but no joy.